# Java Regex to extract the Url of hyperlink (not to use Pattern & Matcher) (Java Regex)?

Tags: java, regex

How to capture the urlOfHref but not to use  Pattern & Matcher.

I am using Gwt plaform & it doesn't have `Pattern & Matcher`.

This code is ok, but it uses  Pattern & Matcher.

```
public static String getTheUrlOfHref(String href){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(href);
    String url = null;
    if (m.find()) {
        url = m.group(1); // this variable should contain the link URL
    }
    return url;
}
```

So How to extract the Url of hyperlink (not to use Pattern & Matcher) (Java Regex)?

Comment: Why do you not want to use Pattern and Matcher? They are *how* you use regular expressions in Java.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158201/gwt-how-to-get-regexpattern-and-matcher-working-in-client-side).

Comment: i don't want to add package for my GWT, too much for a simple thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you could perhaps remove everything you don't need instead?

```
public static String getTheUrlOfHref(String href){
    href = href.replaceAll("^.*?href=\"", "");        // Remove everything before
                                                      // and including href="

    String url = test.substring(0,test.indexOf('"')); // Get everything till
                                                      // first " character
    return url;
}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/AwDUJN)

I didn't put anything to handle errors. I guess you could add that yourself.

---

Or maybe:

```
public static String getTheUrlOfHref(String href){
    String url = href.replaceAll("^.*?href=\"([^\"]*)\".*", "$1");
    return url;
}
```

Comment: Awesome Awesome , i=this is nicer than Pattern which is heavy

Comment: @Tum eh? Pattern will be faster than that!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do more string processing on client side, then you will have to learn how to write Javascript and incorporate it into the GWT-generated javascript code.

See for example [JSNI dynamic function reference in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987438/jsni-dynamic-function-reference-in-gwt).

If you want to do this on server side, then Pattern and Matcher will work just fine.

Comment: I think what they are saying is that they are using a GWT version where `Pattern` and `Matcher` are not available.

Comment: no the method is shared between client + server. In client, it doesn't have Pattern class

Comment: They are not available because GWT is compiling their code into javascript to run on the client, not because they are not available on the server. The server side of a GWT app can do anything any java app can do.

Comment: Server can have Pattern, but client doesn't